# How to display data on next page but getting error in PHP using Codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

When i clicking on link i want to show respected id data on next page using Codeigniter but i getting error of `Undefined variable: id`

This is my index view file

```
<a itemprop="title" style="text-transform: capitalize;color:#29aafe" href="<?=site_url('jobdetails?#'.$row->JPostID);?>"><?=$row->JTitle;?></a>
```

This is mymodel

```
public function getRowByJob($id){
        $query = $this->db->get_where('jobs', array('JPostID' => $id));
        if($query->num_rows() > 0)
            return $data->result();                    
    }
```

this is my controller

```
public function jobdetails(){
        $data = array();
        $data['jobdata'] = $this->mymodel->getRowByJob($id); // it is model method to fetch the record of that users having id = $id
        $this->load->view('jobdetails',$data);          
    }
```

This is my jobdetails view file

```
<?php foreach($jobdata as $row){?>                                        
                 <div class="block-section box-item-details" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/JobPosting">
                    <h2 class="title" itemprop="title" style="text-transform: capitalize;"><?=$row->JTitle;?></h2></div>
```

I am getting following error

[undefined variable:id](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K1I4N.jpg)

[Invalid argument supplied for foreach()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/At4Q5.jpg)

Comment: First off you have named your controller wrong should be Mycontroller.php and not MyController.php same applies for class if you are extending it then needs to go in the core. http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/core_classes.html?highlight=core#extending-core-class

Comment: Ok but its working with other function

Answer (score 0):

there is no `$this->input->get('id');` used inside the controller to get the value of `id` , and also the variable `$id` is not defined inside the controller also , so your controller need to be like below:

```
public function jobdetails(){
        $data = array();
        $id = $this->input->get('id'); // getting $_GET['id'] id from url. and passing it to $id
        $data['jobdata'] = $this->mymodel->getRowByJob($id); // it is model method to fetch the record of that users having id = $id
        $this->load->view('jobdetails',$data);          
    }
```

**Update**

And your model have an invalid return result variable.

```
return $data->result();
```

replace :  `return $data->result();` with `return $query->result();`

Comment: @RomilLodaya that should be also because of that.

Comment: @RomilLodaya that error does not seems to be connected with the code that we have inside the question , tell me what is in file jobdetails.php at line 75

Comment: <?php foreach($jobdata as $row){?>

Comment: @RomilLodaya do check the dump of the $jobdata , what you get in it .

Comment: using print method??

Comment: print_r($jobdata);

Comment: on jobdetails page?

Comment: yup do a dump on jobdetails page , and if you get nothing on there, do a dump inside the controller as well to check if you are getting the data from model or no t

Comment: add print on jobderails page but get nothing then add inside controller after `$data['jobdata'] = $this->mymodel->getRowByJob($id); // it is model method to fetch the record of that users having id = $id
      $this->load->view('jobdetails',$data);print_r($jobdata);    `
but display error `Undefined variable: jobdata`

Comment: @RomilLodaya yes , thats a error, do check that result should be coming to the controller and then pass it into the view , else if $jobdata if null or false, then declare it as empty array then pass it into the view else it will give the if there is a null or bool false in $jobdata , as it is expecting to be an array to be passed to the foreach

Comment: How can i do this to get data to controller?

Comment: @RomilLodaya read update inside my answer , you have invalid result variable inside the model.

Comment: Are you sure , all of the things i mentioned are changed ? , and also be sure that , `model` is loading in constructor or inside the controller method you are calling , and try to `var_dump($jobdata);` and see what you get , as this will tell you , if it's null or false.

Comment: D:\Xampp\htdocs\KDO\application\controllers\MyController.php:33:null

Comment: on line 33 var_dump($jobdata);

Comment: please ,look at the model again , and check if you have made changes about what i said , as the result is null. are you sure that the job exists in the db ? , and are you sure the table name and the JPostID is correct column , and be sure to test the data and add the conditions according to the data , let say , `if(!jobdata) { $jobdata = array(); } else {$jobdata = $jobdata;} `

Comment: Yes i have two records in database

Comment: should i change get_where condition?

Comment: yeah do use something else , maybe `$this->db->where('JPostID','$id); and then $this->db->get('Jobs');` and also apply the valid if else conditions , as you have to validate the data and then pass them to the foreach , else you will always get errors, as you do pass the invalid data to the foreach.

Comment: i change get_where syntex

Answer (score 0):

Try this Way

```
// Model.   
public function getRowByJob($id){
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('jobs');
    $this->db->where('JPostID', $id);
    $query = $this->db->get();

    if($query->num_rows() > 0)
        return $query;                    
}

// Controller.
// Address should be - localhost/Sample/index.php/Controller/jobdetails/5643
// 5643 is $id
public function jobdetails($id){
    $data['jobdata'] = $this->mymodel->getRowByJob($id); // it is model method to fetch the record of that users having id = $id
    $this->load->view('jobdetails', $data);          
}

// View
<?php foreach($jobdata->result() as $row) { ?>                                        
        <div class="block-section box-item-details" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/JobPosting">
            <h2 class="title" itemprop="title" style="text-transform: capitalize;"><?php echo $row->JTitle; ?></h2>
        </div>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: After changing this, u still receive both error.?
first have to fix $id error. foreach error is happened becos of $id error.
What kind of error u received.

Comment: I add `$id = $this->input->get('id');` line in controller before calling model

Comment: Ok. @Romil. Let's do this way. instead of `$id = $this->input->get('id');` put `$id = 1;` for debugging purpose. 1 is JPostID value that exist in database. Try like this and see is there any error.

Comment: Ok. Glad to hear. 
All the best.